# Не работает класс(Работа с клавиатурой)

Tags: awt, java

Привет,ХешКод. Возникла проблема с кодом,он таков:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int WIDTH = 490;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 470;
    private static final String NAME = "KillHero - Game";
    public static InputKey input = new InputKey();
    private int x = 10;
    private int y = 10;

    // public MyCanvas() {
    // addKeyListener(input);
    // }

    public void move() {
        if (x == 0) {
            x = 10;
        }
        if (y == 0) {
            y = 10;
        }

        if (input.left) {
            x--;
        }
        if (input.right) {
            x++;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Castle.png");
        Image img2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Castle2.png");
        int width = img1.getWidth(this);
        int height = img1.getHeight(this);

        int width2 = img2.getWidth(this);
        int height2 = img2.getHeight(this);

        int scale = 4;
        int w = scale * width;
        int h = scale * height;

        int w2 = scale * width2;
        int h2= scale * height2;

        g.drawImage(img1, x, y, (int) w, (int) h, this);
        g.drawImage(img2, x*40, y+2, (int) w2, (int) h2, this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setTitle(NAME);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.requestFocusInWindow();
        frame.addKeyListener(input);
    }

}
```

И второй класс:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class InputKey extends JComponent implements KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public boolean left;
    public boolean right;

    public  MyCanvas cv;

    void FBool() {
        left = right = false;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = true;
        }
        cv.move();
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = false;
        }
        cv.move();
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // bla...bla..bla
    }
}
```

При нажатии какой либо из клавиш,я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Game.InputKey.keyPressed(InputKey.java:28)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
```

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как это исправить?)
Заранее спасибо.
**UPD**
Весь код.

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int WIDTH = 490;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 470;
    private static final String NAME = "KillHero - Game";
    public static InputKey input = new InputKey();
    private int x = 10;
    private int y = 10;

     public MyCanvas() {
     addKeyListener(input);
     }

    public void move() {
        if (x == 0) {
            x = 10;
        }
        if (y == 0) {
            y = 10;
        }

        if (input.left) {
            x--;
        }
        if (input.right) {
            x++;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                "C:\\Users\\дНМ\\workspace\\Game\\image\\Castle.png");

        int width = img1.getWidth(this);
        int height = img1.getHeight(this);

        int scale = 4;
        int w = scale * width;
        int h = scale * height;

        g.drawImage(img1, x, y, (int) w, (int) h, this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setTitle(NAME);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.requestFocusInWindow();
        frame.addKeyListener(input);
    }

}
```

Второй класс.
    package Game;

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class InputKey extends JComponent implements KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public boolean left;
    public boolean right;

    public  MyCanvas cv;

     void FBool(MyCanvas cv) {
            left = right = false;
            this.cv = cv;
        }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = true;
        }
        cv.move();
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = false;
        }
        cv.move();
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // bla...bla..bla
    }
}
```

Comment: что меня действительно умиляет (без сарказма), так это то что большинство вопросов имею класс Game)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

простите а что вам непонятно?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Game.InputKey.keyPressed(InputKey.java:28)
```

1. `NullPointerException` **-** исключение
       указатель(ссылка) указывает на
       ноль(`null`)
2. `Game.InputKey.keyPressed` **-** пакет.класс.функция где произошла ошибка
3. `InputKey.java:28` **-** имя файла и строка где произошла ошибка

ошибка заключается в том что на момент вызова `cv.move();`  `cv` указывает на `null`

ошибка в том что при создании объекта класса `InputKey` переменная `cv` не инициализируется, и нет функции которая это бы делала. (о боже! она ещё и публичная!)

**UPD 06.10.2013**

небольшая ревизия по коду:

1. в классе `MyCanvas` у тебя `public static InputKey input = new InputKey();` модификатор статик означает что ВСЕ экземпляры класса `MyCanvas`  будут иметь один и тот же слушатель  `InputKey`  в итоге если будет 2 канваса то `cv.move();` будет вызываться у одного и тогоже канваса **(я невижу смысла в таком поведении)**
2. так же тебе при создании объекта класса `InputKey` нужно присвоить значение переменной `cv` (то есть инициализировать её) это можно сделать несколькими способами

-через конструктор что то вроде `public InputKey(MyCanvas c){//...}`

-через функцию присвоения `public void setCV(MyCanvas c){//...}`

-другие способы...

(и не забыть вызвать в `MyCanvas`)

Comment: До сих пор не въехал,вроде выше подсказали метод,и cv должны принять какое то значение.Тем более как ее инициализировать? = new MyCanvas(); ?

Comment: вы С\С++ знаете? что такое указатель и ссылка понимаете? в чём между ними разница? в чём разница между (a==b) и (a.equals(b)) ??...

что такое конструктор знаете? а конструктор по умолчанию? а конструктор с параметрами?

а как организована система событий в java?

настоятельно советую разобраться во всём выше перечисленном, иначе дальше у вас будут большие проблемы с программированием...

Comment: что касается вашего кода то вам нужно

сделать функцию инициализации(что это такое понятно?) и передавать в неё ссылку на канвас, и её надо вызывать в канвасе...

но честно скажу ваш код ужасно нелогичен и непонятен (что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать?) я так и не понял зачем у вас всё в статике объявлено... (что делает static понимаете?)

Comment: сделать функцию инициализации(что это такое понятно?) и передавать в неё ссылку на канвас, и её надо вызывать в канвасе... Вообщем вот тут не понял((

Comment: обновил пост


p.s. я крайне настоятельно советую перечитать главу по событиям в java и опробовать на кнопочках что то типо "hello world"

Comment: Если можно еще один вопрос,а что в них писать то?) то что ниже написали? и еще зачем вызывать в MyCanvas ? (и как).Вообщем тяжелый случай...(я невижу смысла в таком поведении) Дык,тогда вот тут ошибка:frame.addKeyListener(input); А без этой строки как я понял нельзя

Comment: ну я уже ну очень подробно всё расписал... и если ты даже этого не понял то тебе надо с самого начала начать изучение java 

купи или скачай книгу по java вот примеры: 

[http://www.skipy.ru/useful/books.html][1]

[http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3693656][2]

ибо у тебя уже сей час сплошные пробелы в программировании, а дальше будет только хуже. Так что вперёд читать!
  [1]: http://www.skipy.ru/useful/books.html
  [2]: http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3693656

Comment: Хорошо,но может все таки напишете каким должен быть код?)

Answer (score 0):

```
private  MyCanvas cv;

    void FBool(MyCanvas cv) {
        left = right = false;
        this.cv = cv;
    }
```

Comment: Gorets,а можете объяснить зачем это надо писать?) так сказать,немножко матана.

Comment: Кстати, не работает почему то... Пост обновил весь код сейчас такой(выше)